# Malloc memory assigned pointer living on a static variable is auto freed or its really a leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, heap-memory, static-memory-allocation

Consider this case:

Using macos leaks -atExit -- have this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *leak = malloc(100);
    return (0);
}
```

that is naturally a leak...which "leaks -atExit" is reporing correctly. then consider this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    static char *test = NULL;

    char *leak = malloc(100);
    test = leak;
    return (0);
}
```

now "leaks -atExit" is reporting no leaks. So what is going on?

are static pointers being auto free()'d at the end? regardless of being on the heap? or... this is really a leak, so its just "leaks tool" cant detect?

Would be cool to actually know whats happening...Thanks!

I cannot access, due to system limitations (old catalina system) to -fsanitize=leaks, nor valgrind, so i cannot test it outside leaks.

Comment: I suspect that the memory is deemed “not leaked” because it is still accessible via the variable with static duration.  Valgrind would probably report the memory as “in use at exit”.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, your memory is lost when exiting.

#### Explanation:

When you create your `static` pointer, it will only allocat 32 or 64 bits (depend on your OS) to store the adress where it's pointing to.

So, when you are assigning the memory allocated on the heap to the `static` pointer, it will **be like** storing an `int` that represent the memory address of the first byte allocated.

When your programme exit, it will only "free" the memory address stored, and not what it's targeting.

Comment: But, if you run the program with a malloc reserved memory allocation, then store the pointer to an static variable... and check for leaks, there is no leak at all. Free has been not called.

The thing is that you get same result, using free or not. Tomorrow i will be able to test using valgrind, will post an update.

Comment: Finally tested it with valgrind, no leaks detected, so i asume having a pointer to heap in a static variable calls free for the pointer at the end of execution.